# How do I get .Net Maui Validation working

Tags: .net, maui, maui-community-toolkit

Does anyone have a good solution for validating UI input in Maui?

The only real solution I saw was the validation in the community toolkit, but that doesn't even work, so looking for someone to advise on what to do...

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't even work". I am using it without any issues. For example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/text-validation-behavior

Comment: Hi @puko I am using the exact code in that link. When I say doesn't even work, I mean the code literally does nothing. I am using .net 7.0 on Android.

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Ok I just worked out the problem. It turns out it was inheriting a style from somewhere else and this was preventing the invalid style from taking effect. I had assumed the invalid style would override every other style, but seems not. Either way it seems to be working now. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few ways to make such validation.

One way is using inheriting ObservableValidator.

```
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableValidator
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Text is Required Field!")]
    [MinLength(5,ErrorMessage = "Text length is minimum 5!")]
    [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Text length is maximum 10!")]
    [ObservableProperty]
    string _text = "Hello";

    [ObservableProperty]
    bool _isTextValid;

    [ObservableProperty]
    string _error;

    [RelayCommand]
    void Validate()
    {
        ValidateAllProperties();
        
        if (HasErrors)
            Error = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, GetErrors().Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
        else
            Error = String.Empty;

        IsTextValid = (GetErrors().ToDictionary(k => k.MemberNames.First(), v => v.ErrorMessage) ?? new Dictionary<string, string?>()).TryGetValue(nameof(Text), out var error);
    }
}
```

This is the way you can do it in your ViewModel.

The second way is using behaviors.

```
 <Entry.Behaviors>
                <toolkit:EmailValidationBehavior InvalidStyle="{StaticResource InvalidEntryStyle}"
                                                      IsValid="{Binding EmailIsValid}"                                                
                                                      ValidStyle="{StaticResource NormalEntryStyle}"                                                     
                                                      Flags="ValidateOnValueChanged" >
                </toolkit:EmailValidationBehavior>
 </Entry.Behaviors>
```

This is how I do it with the XAML.

I use both, depending on what I want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The ObservableValidator method seems to work well - thanks. Can't get the behaviours to work though. Nothing happens with the behaviour in place.

Comment: Ignore my comment - turns out an inherited style was overriding it. Just need to work out how to prevent that from happening. Thanks